# How can I create documentation with all properties which can be overridden in `yaml` file of my spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml, app.yaml

Can I generate documentation from `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file?

I have autogenerated file `spring-configuration-metadata.json` with properties. It's useful for autocomplete in IDE. But I wont to give documentation to administrators. I can give them JSON file, but maybe there is something which can convert JSON to HTML or something else?

I just want to create full list properties which can be overridden in `yaml` file and pass it to somebody who deploys an application.

Comment: This is a cool idea, I don't think that this already exists for spring. There is a comparable plugin for swagger to generate a html file from swagger.json using  a handlebars html template: https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin